# Display a table when click on a button using angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, django

Hi i am working on a django powered project.
I have a button in my html as follows:

```
<tr align="left"><b><span style="background-color:white;"><button>{{ k }}</button></span></b></tr>
```

Am planning to use angularJS to display a table below once the user click the button above. I have the cotrolller below as follows:

```
% block extrascript %}


    {{ngapp}}.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $resource) {

    });
{% endblock %}
```

Sorry for the less amount of angularjs. Am very much new to angularJS. Can I have some suggestions guys? Thanks in advance

Comment: How to use ng-click, ng-show in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something this:

```
<table ng-show="show">

 </table>
 <button ng-click="show=!show">{{ k }}</button>


 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.show = false; // Hide it initially 

    });
```

Comment: Yes Praveen. But how can I do ng-show or ng-hide inside that function?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want Praveen. Actually my tables are under a for loop. So there will be multiple tables. As per your answer when I click the button all my tables are getting displayed once i click the button. I just want the specific table to be displayed. How do I prevent that?

Comment: Then you must be having many buttons also right? So, You can bind different variables to each table and its corresponding button. like show1, show2, etc.